# Size definitions in Android layout

Tags: android, layout

Looking at Android samples, I see different size definitions int .xml layout files, like:

```
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:textSize="15pt"
android:layout_marginRight="10px"
...
```

Where can I find definition of these constants: pt, dp, px etc. ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension